# ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s) - School project

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT naam, adres, postcode, plaats, telefoon  
FROM klanten 
WHERE plaats IN (SELECT * FROM(
                    (SELECT plaats, COUNT(plaats) AS W 
                     FROM klanten 
                     GROUP BY plaats 
                     ORDER BY W DESC LIMIT 1) AS T));
```

So, where did I goof? Where is my syntax mistake or am I derping.

My goal is to print name (naam), adres (address), place (plaats), telephone (telefoon) from the city where the most customers (klanten) live.And before you ask, I'm doing this for a school project and we have to use an older version of MySQL that doesn't allow LIMIT 1 in subqueries. That's why the `Select * FROM` is there with the subquery.

Comment: Your sub-query returns 2 columns. Only 1 is expected.

Comment: You are doing it in a too complicated way. There is no need for nested subqueries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you are trying to write looks like this:

```
SELECT naam, adres, postcode, plaats, telefoon
FROM klanten
WHERE plaats IN (SELECT plaats
                 FROM klanten
                 GROUP BY plaats
                 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                 LIMIT 1
                );
```

The syntax error is because the `IN` subquery is returning two columns -- that is pretty obvious from the message.  The subquery in the subquery is not necessary; you can `ORDER BY` an aggregation expression.

Also, `IN` is a bit misleading.  You can just use `=`.

Comment: It would work, it I was only allowed to upgrade the version of MySQL we are using in class... Now I get "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support "Limit & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery.'   That's why I had to add the select * from and alais at the end. But edit, when I changed the subquery, with an alais at the end... it works. Thanks!

Comment: Life would be too easy if MySQL would permit `IN (.. LIMIT n)` subqueries.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel . . . I very much agree.

Comment: @Jonez . . . Use `=` instead.